# append list of values to sublists

Tags: python, list, iterator, iteration, sublist

How do you append each item of one list to each sublist of another list?

```
a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
b = [1,2,3]
```

Result should be:

```
[['a','b','c',1],['d','e','f',2],['g','h','i',3]]
```

Keep in mind that I want to do this to a very large list, so efficiency and speed is important.

I've tried:

```
for sublist,value in a,b:
    sublist.append(value)
```

it returns 'ValueError: too many values to unpack'

Perhaps a listindex or a listiterator could work, but not sure how to apply here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]            
b = [1,2,3]

for ele_a, ele_b in zip(a, b):
    ele_a.append(ele_b)
```

Result:

```
>>> a
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['d', 'e', 'f', 2], ['g', 'h', 'i', 3]]
```

The reason your original solution did not work, is that `a,b` does create a `tuple`, but not what you want.

```
>>> z = a,b
>>> type(z)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> z
([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']], [1, 2, 3])
>>> len(z[0])
3
>>> for ele in z:
...    print ele
... 
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']] #In your original code, you are
[1, 2, 3]                                           #unpacking a list of 3 elements 
                                                    #into two values, hence the 
                                                    #'ValueError: too many values to unpack'

>>> zip(a,b)  # using zip gives you what you want.
[(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1), (['d', 'e', 'f'], 2), (['g', 'h', 'i'], 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution:

```
a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
b = [1,2,3]

for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i].append(b[i])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, using list comprehension:

```
a = [(a[i] + b[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the sublists, adding one item at a time:

```
    for i in range(0,len(listA)):
         listA.append(listB[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> [l1+[l2] for l1, l2 in zip(a,b)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['d', 'e', 'f', 2], ['g', 'h', 'i', 3]]
```

You can also abuse a side effect of list comprehensions to get this done in place:

```
>>> [l1.append(l2) for l1, l2 in zip(a,b)]
[None, None, None]
>>> a
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['d', 'e', 'f', 2], ['g', 'h', 'i', 3]]
```